# Renew/change the IP address of an iPhone programmatically in iOS 6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am developing an iPad/iPhone app for my own personal use on my own devices (i.e. not for submission to the App Store).

My app needs to change the IP addresses assigned to the cellular data (not WiFi) connection of the iPhone/iPad at regular intervals. I understand the best way to do this is to put the device in Airplane mode briefly, however it would appear that this is only possible using private APIs on a jailbroken device.

Is there a way to do this on a non-jailbroken device?

Comment: There is no way to do this. You can't even reliably detect if they're in airplane mode.

Comment: For the time being, as in iOS 6.0 this is not possible. I can guess that it will never be. Furthermore, even if you put it in airplane mode, there is guarantee that you will certainly obtain a new IP address, it all depends on how your ISP handles things.